# How to activate the My Location UI button of an embedded Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have embedded Google Maps in my app, and I have made it such that it can find the current user's location, etc. However it is not working perfect.

What I do have noticed is that when I click on the *My Location* UI Button, as seen here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity on the section **My Location Button**, that then it *does work perfectly*.

So my question is, given a `GoogleMap` object, is there a way to programatically click on that UI Button?

Answer (score 0):

Get the current user location in lat lng, then

```
 CameraUpdate center=
    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat,
                                             lng));
CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

map.moveCamera(center);
map.animateCamera(zoom);
```

Ref:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views?hl=fr-FR#moving_the_camera

> I have embedded Google Maps in my app, and I have made it such that it
>   can find the current user's location, etc. However it is not working
>   perfect.

Are you not getting the location? Or are you unable to move the map to that location.

Comment: As it currently is, somewhat like that, the obtained location is by far correct and it takes 10 seconds to obtain. While the *My Location* has it immediatly and perfectly.

Comment: Are you getting location like this? mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

Comment: No, because that is surely an old outdated location. (Like a random one along my route when I was travelling), I'm using the Fused Location provider and then doing a single request.

Comment: From what I know, getting the current accurate location is not yet possible. You can use PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY to get the most accurate one, but it'll take time as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to interact with the `MyLocationButton`, but enable it and add a click listener to it.
The listener was added because of the [Issue 4789](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4789&q=apitype=Android2&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal) and you can find it in the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener.html).

If you want to get your location updates faster don't use only GPS to get an update (you are using `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` I guess). Because this will only get the most accurate accuracy. With lower priority the `LocationClient` will get your updates faster but not that accurate, because it will use WiFi and Cell in addition. That way GoogleMaps is working too.

Otherwise you will have no chance to get a GPS fix.